# Why doesn't Volumetric follow the shape of Mesh in Eevee?

Tags: mesh, eevee-render-engine, volumetrics

So I was in the middle of making a ball-shaped smoke, but the volumetric effect didn't work following the basic shape. It remains cube in Eevee Blender 2.8; while in Cycle it works, but in Cycle it takes thousands of years for Render.[image]

Comment: know i'm a bit late, but.. into the density add a math: Greater Than, and set it to one

Answer (score 11):

Eevee's support for volumetrics is quite limited.

From the blender manual:

> *Eevee’s goal is to be an interactive render engine. Some features may not be there yet or may be impossible to implement into Eevee’s architecture without compromising performance*.

Read: [Eevee Render Limitations](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/eevee/limitations.html)

> Volumes Objects
>
> Object volume shaders will affect **the whole bounding box of the object**. The shape of the volume must be adjusted using procedural texturing inside the shader.

What that means is that the volumetric shader will always be a cube or a cuboid.

As far as I know it is meant more for haze and atmospheric effects, so volume would be used on volumetric domains, not so much in detailed meshes made of smoke or dust.

Maybe someone that actually cares for Eevee can clarify.

Comment: Read also [Cycles vs Eevee, 15 limitation of real time rendering](https://cgcookie.com/articles/blender-cycles-vs-eevee-15-limitations-of-real-time-rendering)

Answer (score 7):

Here is the solution that works with *Emission Shader*, *Principled Volume* and *Volume Scatter*.

You can try the spherical mode of the Gradient Texture. I am still experimenting and I want to make it transparent in the middle, but I can't work it out yet. And for more interesting results, maybe try to multiply the *Gradient* Texture with the noise and play around with the texture coordinates.
This is specific for Spheres only !

[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 2):

I know it's been a while since this was posted but I had the same issue recently. I used the same methodology shown in the screenshot by Alecheck. I placed a color ramp in between the math node and the principle volume. Adjusting the black and white sliders kept the fog effect within the sphere. [image]