# Principled Volume outside containing Object

Tags: volumetrics

I am using the 2.8 RC2

I want to create a Material that is seethrough and colored as there will be an object inside that must be visible. It will be a red Light Emitting Diode with innards.

Therefore Under "Material" > "Blend Mode" I chose Additive.

Just having a red "Principled BSDF" go into the Material Output's Surface is not enough as it is way too light on its own.
Therefore i took a Principled Volume and put it into the Output's Volume slot. The color is about the same now as it would be with just an opaque surface.

But there is a problem:

The volume is also outside the containing object in what looks like a cubid around my object.
I created a MRE with just a sphere with a nontransparent red surface and added volume the same way but in green for contrast.
[image: MRE]

I tried switching from EVEE to Cycles and even disabled GPU acceleration to exclude error sources.

I tried the same with Blender 2.79b (Cycles) and it works. No Volume outside of the object.

Is this a bug or did I forget something?

Comment: This is a limitation of Eevee, see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/141443/why-doesnt-volumetric-follow-the-shape-of-mesh-in-eevee In Cycles this works fine.