# thickness dependent transparency

Tags: materials, transparency

[image: Original shader setting]I am using a transparent material but it seems that I only have a transparent surface. How can I get the result that a thinner part of my object is more transparent than a thicker part. I now the answer may be simple but I tried a lot of options but there are simly too many for trial and error. Also I don't find anything like that in the questions. I am using eevee.

I tried the solution with the principal volume and I cranked up the volumetrics samples. The effect is weird. See the second picture.

[image: Image of the result of volume shader]

This happens for all the volume shaders. The right object is a cylinder in reality, the left one is a sphere. In a third image I show the shader setting that I have used.
[image: Shader setting for result in second image]

Comment: Hello :). Please add an image of your material nodes. This can depend on how you're achieving transparency.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have added the node picture. The volume settings do not seem to have any influence.

Comment: Did you try to add some volume shader?

Comment: Hi :). You connected surface shader (Principled BSDF) into volume input. That won't work well. Are you trying to achieve smoke?

Comment: I tried (Volume absorption). It gets me a weird effect. Although I have a cylinder I get a kind of square cushion with some wavyness. I have no idea where this is coming from.

Comment: I tried various connections. I don't want to achieve smoke. I need a coloured particle to pass through some semitransparent stuff. Depending on the depth the visibility should be better or worse. So i need some absorption in the volume which becomes large over distance.

Comment: @Bruno To tell exactly what I mean: I do not need something which becomes opaque when thick. I need something like tinted glass. Red glass will be darker (or seem darker) but still transparent when thick and lighter when thin. When it is very thin it will be almost invisible. That's what I need. Maybe I was not really clear about it before.

Comment: can you find any photo or illustration example?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't. What I am trying to model is a particle in a magnetic field of varying strength. To explain: I am a prof. for physics and due to Covid I now have to do my lecture online. So it is nothing real that I want to show. By the degree of transparency I want to indicate the strength of the magnetic field. But I often need this kind of effect and I guess it should be normal that a tick coloured pane lets less light through than a thin one. In reality cloured smoke would probably be the closest thing because in glass you always have the index of refraction coming into play.

Answer (score 2):

You can use *Principled Volume* for that.

- Use the *Density* value to adjust the strength
- Larger volumes obscure objects more
- For Eevee, crank up the samples in  *Render Tab > Volumetrics*.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried the volume shaders (wanted to post this but the website just had an error. They give the strange result you can see in the image. The internal structure of the result even seems to change with time. Weird.

Comment: Just checked because you had set the material output to All and I had used Eevee. Doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @GeorgSchmidt Eevee doesn't support volumes with shapes other than a cuboid. It currently uses the bounding box of the objects, see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/141443/why-doesnt-volumetric-follow-the-shape-of-mesh-in-eevee

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be the point. I switched to cycles and now it works. Thanks to all of you.