# How do I stop Flip-Fluids generating smoke/fog effect over the water?

Tags: add-on, fluid-simulation

I just recently got started with Flip-Fluids in blender and it was working fine for a bit, but then I found that there was a fog generated over the liquid.

I am trying to generate a fog inside the liquid to be used as a shading and make it not clear. I don't know what setting I changed to get this.

The fog moves with the water stretches to cover the water completely in all directions.

**How do I stop this from happening?**

[image: Water flowing though holes]

[image: water hitting ball gif]

Comment: What rendering engine do you use? If it is EEVEE, please be aware that presently the volume shader can't react to mesh topology and will always use the bounding box of the mesh for volume calculation. See here for example: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/141443/why-doesnt-volumetric-follow-the-shape-of-mesh-in-eevee

Comment: @haarigertroll Thank you, you solved my problem that has been plaguing me for the last week.